# Simulation Models and Schematic Simulation Errors in Altium Designer 16.1

Tags: simulation, altium

I am trying to use simulation of Altium for the first time and i established a simple circuit which was mentioned as "Circuit.jpg" however i have obtained some errors when i run the simulation. My first question is related to fix these errors and how i can put an ac source and make transient analysis on Altium Sİmulation.

My second question is about simulating models. In a schematic library, i tried to add a diode's simulation model. Firstly, i have downloaded a full list of spice models of Diodes Inc. and then i have saved this .txt file as a ".mdl" file as i metioned "diodes-spice-models.mdl" I have select as model name "DEFAULT_DI_B340A" from the browse list like"All_Diode_Models.jpg". My question is that this method is correct or should i copy my model and make a new model and add it to component like i mentioned "Single_Model_B340A.jpg". I also added the "B34AA.mdl" file. If you share your ideas and comments i will be happy because i really desire to work using Altium Simulation. Thank you so much.

These are the files and images of circuits;

**1.** http://www.diodes.com/spice/downloadall (This can be dowloaded as .txt and can be saved as .mdl)

**2.** This is the model of B340A obtained by the file above.

`*SRC=B340;DI_B340;Diodes;Si;  40.0V  3.00A  5.00ns   Diodes Inc. Schottky
.MODEL DI_B340 D  ( IS=9.90n RS=14.0m BV=40.0 IBV=500u
+ CJO=464p  M=0.333 N=0.775 TT=7.20n )`

**3.** Circuit.jpg
[image: enter image description here-]

**4.** Single_Model_B340A.jpg
[image]

**5.** All_Diode_Models.jpg
[image]